# Cron Expression to schedule a job

Tags: java, cron, expression, apache-nifi

I would like to run my code on specific schedule.So i need a cron expression to schedule a job for every 12th day of the month by excluding saturdays and sundays (means scheduling a job only on weekdays for every 12th day of the month). Is this possible to schedule ??

Can someone help for the solution to get me out here

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's easily [possible](https://crontab.guru/#5_4_*/12_*_1-5).

```
5 4 */12 * 1-5
```

> “At 04:05 on every 12th day-of-month if it's on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday.”

**Edit**: I misunderstood the question, sorry. I don't think that's possible only with the CRON string itself.

As an easy solution proposal: just schedule the task itself every business day (e.g. `5 4 * * 1-5`) and then check at the start of the job if it is the 12th [business day of the month](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/calculate-business-days/). If so, start your business process and if not just exit.

Comment: I required to run the Job only on 12th day of every month excluding weekends ( for example present month 12th day is on 16th and next month 12th day is on 18th) Is this possible

Comment: Ah now I get the question, sorry. You only want to count working days regarding the 12th day? I'm not quite sure if this is possible. I'll have a look